# What is the most quiet way I can keep my laptop running?

Tags: 11.04, screen, noise

I have my laptop as a server for [my website](http://alvarberglind.se) and during the following 48 hours I want it to be online non-stop! I want to know how I can keep it as quiet as possible, and I also want to eliminate any light there might be from the screen.

I'm a student and I sleep in the same room.

- How can I keep it as quiet as possible?
- How can I eliminate any light from the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the screen brightness down as far as possible and put a cloth over the screen to mask the light. Put a quiet USB cooling pad under the laptop so the noisy built in fan doesn't have to work as hard.  In the power management settings, set the "Spin down hard disks when possible" to true. And of course, mute the volume!  `xset dpms force off` turns the screen off. Moing the mouse or pressing a key turns it back on.

Comment: You didn't even upvote. Liar.

Comment: Take your command and leave: $ 'xset dpms force off' turns it off. Moving the mouse or a keypress turns it back on

Comment: Your'e welcome. I even upvoted your question, that's just the kind of nice guy that I am. Unlike jrg...